# How do I count blank cells in spark sql using case when statement?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm getting a zero count on using this code which I know is not correct, what is wrong?

```
SELECT CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN column != '' AND column IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)as int) as completecount
FROM clouddatabase.Table1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `NULL` safe comparator:

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN column <=> '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as int)
```

Comment: Thanks, this brings back a count, although only when I use it on its own. It still brings back '0' incorrectly if I do column <=> '' AND column IS NOT NULL.  It is important I count columns both not empty and not null, but I'm not sure how Apache Spark does this as it is definitely different to SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
df.show()
+----+
| col|
+----+
|   a|
|null|
|   c|
|    |
|   e|
+----+

df.agg(sum(when('col.isNull || 'col === "",0).otherwise(1)).as("count")).show()
```

OR

```
df.filter(!(df("col").isNull || df("col") === "")).count

//+-----+
//|count|
//+-----+
//|    3|
//+-----+
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but I'm not using a data frame, I'm querying table data using a sql notebook.